# Sequence with every proper subsequence converges but the sequence doesn't

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here by proper subsequence I mean a subsequence which leaves out infinitely many indices. For example $1/2,1/3, \ldots $  is not a proper subsequence of $1,1/2, \ldots $

Comment: Sounds rather unlikely to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of sequence where every subsequence of specific type converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893734/convergence-of-sequence-where-every-subsequence-of-specific-type-converges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible. Let's say $a_n$ doesn't converge, but every proper subsequence converges. Then the sequences $a_{2n}$, $a_{2n+1}$ converge, so in order for $a_n$ not to converge we need $a_{2n}\to L_1$, $a_{2n+1}\to L_2$ with $L_1\neq L_2$. Now consider the sequence $a_{3n}$. The subsequence $a_{6n}$ converges to $L_1$ and $a_{6n+3}$ to $L_2$, so $a_{3n}$ does not converge, which is a contradiction.